# Loading Git Bashes with different background colours

Tags: bash, shell, command-prompt, git-bash

I need to have a couple of bashes open pointing to different repos.

I'd like to have them with different background colours so it's less confusing to see.

I assume that the colour options aren't specific to the Git Bash as the Windows Command Prompt has the same options in the properties window.

I know that the OS or whatever must be storing these somewhere, as they are persisted between sessions.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

press alt+spacebar or click on the git bash window's icon on top left, select "properties" then choose the tab "colors" and select the desired color

Comment: Aye, know I can do that.  I can change the properties before opening it as well, I was hoping I could have two shortcuts with different properties though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there's a way to pass this on to the shell instance's host cmd window when you start, but you can definitely wrap your existing call in a customized window: make a shortcut to `cmd` and then pass it the color option as well as a command - in this case, to start the shell process.

Would look like this in the shortcut's Target properties: `%windir%\system32\cmd.exe /T:24 c:\path\to\msysgit\sh.exe` (or path to your current shortcut, since there will maybe be flags or options used there).

Comment: Aye, I've had a look in there, all there is is `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login -i`, but it must be storing the colour options somewhere as they are persisted between sessions.

Comment: But what's stopping you from hosting the shell instance in your own command window, thereby allowing you control over the color scheme?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  The bash is hosted in the same something as the command prompt (I'm assuming), but I don't know how to set the colour scheme without using the properties window.

Comment: "How to set colour scheme without using the properties window" - this is what my post addresses. Call the `cmd` program from a shortcut with the /T option. `/T:<colour1><colour2>` sets the colour scheme; the next argument to `cmd` is the path to your `sh.exe` (with `--login -i`, or alternatively to your existing shortcut). This in effect would wrap the `sh.exe` session in a custom `cmd` session, allowing you to control the colors via /T.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows environment you can use `color` command. It changes font and background color simultaneously.
What you need to is to run `color` command before running `sh.exe`. Start `cmd.exe` and type:

```
color EA
"c:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe"
```

This example makes windows terminal green-yellow.
Run `color /?` and `sh.exe --help` for more.